# Webpack require/import acts lazily on client, not on server

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

It's hard to isolate this problem, so please bear with me.

I have two files, called `index.js` and `feed.js`. They are both run isomorphically.

index.js

```
const feed = require('./feed');
console.log('feed', JSON.stringify(feed));
console.log('feed.default', feed.default);
(global || window).feed = feed;
```

feed.js

```
console.log('inside feed');
export default 5;
```

On the server, the following gets printed in order:

```
inside feed
feed {"default":5}
feed.default 5
```

But on the client the output is

```
feed {}
feed.default undefined
inside feed
```

and when I actually check `window.feed` on the client (this is after all of this has occurred, of course), it's configured properly and has all the right data in it.

Does anyone know why this is or how I can prevent or work around it cleanly? I believe `feed` should always be populated with the correct stuff synchronously by the statement after the require.

The webpack config is a little complicated, but it's *mostly* the same as [this one](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js).

I'd be willing to believe it's some kind of race condition (the server has already required it), but I don't understand why it would be lazily loaded to begin with. Because I'm using babel-node and react-hot-loader, I can't exactly step through what's happening inside of webpack_require, but I'm pretty sure this isn't the intended behavior so I figure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I didn't accurately explain the problem because it's a relatively large application. The problem turned out to be a circular dependency. Not sure why it was only happening on the client, but that's what it was.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of webpack optimization plugins enabled for the client. Do you really know what they do and how they do it? Try disabling them, especially `AggressiveMergingPlugin`. Make your configuration as simple as possible.

The only time I had a similar issue was when I accidentally had two modules that require each other. Maybe one of the plugins is doing some module reordering magic and causes a similar condition to arise somehow. Just a guess.

Failing that, examine the contents of the bundle that webpack generates. `debugger;` statements are useful to jump into the right places.

Comment: I read the documentation on each of them, and none of them implies that they do what is happening. Debugger statements don't seem to work in this application, but it might simply be because of hot reloader. Will update if any of these methods help. Thanks!